# What is the difference between saying "I wasn't knowing" and "I didn't know"?

Tags: grammar, differences, progressive-aspect, stative-verbs

I was wondering what is the difference between *I wasn't knowing* and  *I didn't know*? If I say, *I wasn't knowing*, I am talking about something unknown in past, the act of *not knowing* is finished, it means that I know it now, but before it was unknown to me.

Comment: In English, "I didn't know" is used to indicate the past tense of "I do not know" even though the *not knowing* was continuous over a period of time. It is the same for synonymous verbs: I wasn't aware, I didn't realize, I wasn't cognizant, I wasn't conscious. "I wasn't knowing"  isn't used in English.

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: I know (ha!) the "answer" is common knowledge for native speakers, but the "why" behind it would be interesting to explore. If "know" is a stative verb, does that mean it expresses an involuntary or non volitive state? Is *to know* really "static" as oerkelens' answer claims it to be? Can't you *know* something better over time?

Comment: [I wasn't knowing](http://books.google.it/books?id=Ci0UAQAAIAAJ&q=%22I+wasn%27t+knowing%22&dq=%22I+wasn%27t+knowing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5DaeU_DrLOGM7AbJ9YHYDQ&redir_esc=y) that particular usage makes sense to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference would be that any continuous tense of *know* will be frowned upon. "I am knowing", "I was knowing", "I will be knowing" all make little sense, as we don't perceive the act of knowing as a feasible thing. *Knowing* something is a state, not an action.

I can say I am biking, I am painting, I am thinking.

But when I describe a state, a static property which does not describe any action, a continuous tense is confusing. At any moment in time, I either *know* or I do *not know*. But in neither case am I actively performing an action of *knowing*.

So the correct sentence would be:

> I didn't know.

Comment: Nicely explained. A marginal case is ***to think*** - where *"I'm thinking"* means I'm currently engaged in the act of thinking [about *something*], but *"I think"* probably means I'm specifically thinking about [Cartesian philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesianism). And with an object clause, it would normally be *"I think this is a good answer"*. I wouldn't like to say if there's general agreement about exactly what if any difference it would make if I said *"I'm thinking this is a good answer"*. (Perhaps you'd like to have a go at that! :)

Comment: my point is , there is a continuous time unknowing that thing and you just knew 
Is it also correct to say  I didnt know ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps a non-native speaker in any way. This question should (could) have been asked on ELL instead.

Comment: Moreover, there's the question of logic regarding "any continuous tense of *know* will be frowned upon" -- Why? By whom? What about the semantics of 'being aware' vs. 'knowing'? How can a learner understand these points?

Comment: @rabarkareem - there _is_ no such thing as a continuous _act_ of knowing, it is a fixed state, a property. "I know" is no different from "I am Dutch" - it is not something that I can actively be doing. So if in the past there was a time you did not know something, yes, you always say "I didn't know".

Comment: @Kris - This question could indeed have been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). I sometimes do assume that someone has a reason to ask a question here, rather than on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't knowing or I didn't know

The first is incorrect, use the second form. If you want to convey that you now know, use

> I didn't know then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the question as stated can really be answered as one would never say "I wasn't knowing".

You should definitely go with "I didn't know", "I wasn't aware" or something to that regard.

Knowing something isn't an action but rather a mental state, the [continuous form](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/present_continuous.php) is not used for this.