# Can we use verbs of perception in the present continuous?

Tags: tenses

Title says it all. Kindly inform what other verbs can't be used with present continuous.

Comment: To improve the chances of a good response, avoid using the title as the sole source of the question: repeat it in the main text and expand upon why you need some examples etc.

Comment: The verbs you are asking about are called _stative verbs_. You will find plenty of lists and explanations if you run a web search on this term. The topic has also been covered several times on this site. Here for example: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187261/stative-verbs-in-the-continuous-form

Answer (score 0):

Verbs of perception definitely can be present continuous. For example:

- Are you hearing this?
- The dog is smelling his food.
- I'm seeing it but I'm not believing it.
- They're feeling unloved.

I found [one website](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-continuous-meaning.htm) claiming stative verbs can't ordinarily be present continuous, but I disagree. For example, the following are all fine, despite that website's assertion:

- I'm hating/liking/loving how I look right now.
- That's right: I'm preferring to stay indoors rather than have to go outside with you.
- I'm not agreeing or disagreeing with you.
- I'm imagining something really outrageous.
- This call is concerning your overdue bill.

A few of these are *unusual* sentences because **they're not words we normally intend to have such a sense of immediacy, but that doesn't make the sentences ungrammatical, or even strange to hear**. For that reason it's hard to imagine real sentences that use "belong" or "matter" in present continuous, but it wouldn't be ungrammatical per se.